# How do I run NetBeans (or ANY .app) as SUDO on OSX?

Tags: macos, sudo

In addition to running other applications elevated (a bridge which I will burn when to it I get), I need to run NetBeans elevated in order to debug this application that I am writing.

I would really, really, REALLY rather not get into the specifics of the application itself, and stick to the topic at hand - OSX, NetBeans, and SUDO.

A google search yielded nothing relevant.

How do I run NetBeans (or, really, any .app) as SU or SUDO on OSX?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the executable within the `.app`:

```
sudo /Applications/AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName
```

Comment: Okay so... beyond doing that by the terminal, is there any other way to make that happen? As in with Windows you can right-click and say "Run as administrator", or go to the properties and select advanced and click the checkbox that says "Run as administrator".

Comment: No, OS X doesn't have anything like that in the GUI AFAIK. Note that running as administrator is not the same as running as root. Normally if you want to run something as administrator, you would use Fast User Switching to open an admin login session.